# JSON post to Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am starting with Web Services in Spring, so I am trying to develop small application in Spring + JSON + Hibernate. I have some problem with HTTP-POST. I created a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/workers/addNewWorker", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String addNewWorker(@RequestBody Test test) throws Exception {
    String name = test.name;
    return name;
}
```

And my model Test looks like:

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1764970284520387975L;
public String name;

public Test() {
}
}
```

By POSTMAN I am sending simply JSON {"name":"testName"} and I always get error;

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

I imported Jackson library. My GET methods works fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: When you sent the request using POSTMAN, do you specify header "Content-type: application/json"?

Comment: Ok now work. My problem was Content-type. And my second question. How to work with entity relations in JSON Spring? I have entity Workers (when I have reference to class Address)
And JSON: 
         {
  "address":{"street":"asdas","homeNo":"123","flatNo":"123","postcode":"123","city":"asdas"}, "name":"asd","email":"asd","pesel":"123","phone":"asd","employmentType":"asd","position":"asd","desc":"asd"
}

And when I trying to POST into Workers object I get previous error. What I am doing wrong. Thanks for last replys.

Comment: Did you specified "Accept: application/json" in the header?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Convert your JSON object to JSON String using

**JSON.stringify({"name":"testName"})**

or manually. **@RequestBody expecting json string** instead of json object.

Note:stringify function having issue with some IE version, firefox it will work

verify the syntax of your ajax request for POST request. **processData:false** property is required in ajax request

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:urlName,
    type:"POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: jsonString, //Stringified Json Object
    async: false,    //Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation
    cache: false,    //This will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser  
     processData:false, //To avoid making query String instead of JSON
     success: function(resposeJsonObject){
        // Success Action
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = urlPattern , method = RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody Test addNewWorker(@RequestBody Test jsonString) {

    //do business logic
    return test;
}
```

`@RequestBody` -Covert Json object to java

`@ResponseBody` - convert Java object to json

Comment: How to covert JSON Array Objects(`[{a: 1}, {a: 2}]`) to java?

Comment: @RequestBody will not accept List/Array directly for that you need to create a wrapper class and set the list to it.

Comment: Your object structure look like this                                class Test{
 Integer id;
    List<Person> personList;
   //getter and setters
}
JSON:
{id:1,personList:[{a: 1}, {a: 2}]}

Comment: I have already a class and have a method with annotation as `@RequestMapping(value = urlPattern , method = RequestMethod.POST)`. One thing, I don't understand why we give `Integer id` here. I have one more doubt, Does the setter and getter need all properties in array objects? That is first array element `{a: 1}` can be anything `{c: 1, g: 5}` like so. I don't know the perfect structure that is passing from front end. Can we write getter and setter methods in this case?

Comment: Aha, I was missing @RequestBody! Thanks for the post, helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the getters and setters for all the fields that have been defined in the model `Test` class --

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1764970284520387975L;

    public String name;

    public Test() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using application/* instead. And use JSON.maybeJson() to check the data structure in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following thing if you want to use json as a http request and response. So we need to make changes in [context].xml

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter messageConverters so that Jackson API kicks in and converts JSON to Java Beans and vice versa. By having this configuration, we will be using JSON in request body and we will receive JSON data in the response.

I am also providing small code snippet for controller part:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.DUMMY_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody Employee getDummyEmployee() {
    logger.info("Start getDummyEmployee");
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(9999);
    emp.setName("Dummy");
    emp.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    empData.put(9999, emp);
    return emp;
}
```

So in above code emp object will directly convert into json as a response. same will happen for post also.

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--)

> The consumable media types of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

the producer is used to narrow the primary mapping, you send request should specify the exact header to match it.