# Spring returning get not supported even though i send post request

Tags: java

I used

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getCPBankAccounts(@RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest)


 var ajaxData={"id" : $("#id").val(),
"name" : $("#name").val(),
"age" : $("#age").val()
};
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
         url: localhost:8080/something,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
        data : JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
          success: function(response) {
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
          }
        });
```

I am getting

```
GET request for "http://localhost:8080/something" resulted in 200 ()
2018-03-09 12:41:13 - Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@2f0ccb34]
2018-03-09 12:41:13 - Written [{"httpStatus":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","errorCode":"ERROR","status":"FAILED","errorMessage":null,"data":"Request method 'GET' not supported"}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@2f0ccb34]
2018-03-09 12:41:13 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

Please help me where i am going wrong

Comment: Change method to RequestMapping method to GET i.e. @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: But i want to send  a post request

Comment: In that case take a look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550418/json-post-to-spring-controller

Comment: Please post a capture of the HTTP request from your browser's debug Network tab.

Comment: Accept 
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Length 
114
Content-Type 
application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie 
JSESSIONID=sessionid
Origin 
http://localhost:8080
Referer 
http://localhost:8080/index.html
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0