# can POST parameters be sent using Content Type application/json?

Tags: post, post-parameter

As far as I understand, POST parameters can be sent using `Content-Type` only either `multipart/form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Is that right?
I want to send the parameters wrapped in JSON. Is that possible?
Will the parameters in the request

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json

{"username": "test","password": "test"}
```

be identified as `username=test&password=test`?

Comment: Spring Framework doesn't seem to identify such parameters, that is the reason why I'm asking the question.

Comment: An HTTP POST can be sent [with 'any' Content-Type](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5); such a Content-Type restriction *might* come different HTML/browser/etc contexts, but it's *not* an HTTP restriction.

Comment: It's probably the case that the application/Spring "hasn't been setup" to correctly work with such an incoming encoding - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550418/json-post-to-spring-controller , https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/ (try some research, there are very few new snowflakes.. and "posting JSON to Spring" is a thing)

Comment: `Content-Type` can be sent as `application/json`, You can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/10109833)